# ImportError: No module named psycopg2 after install

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I've run `sudo pip install psycopg2` successfully from my `virtualenv` on my ubuntu server.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost/mydb"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.debug = True

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))

@app.route('/users/', methods = ['GET'])
def users():
    query = "SELECT id, name FROM users"

    results = User.query.from_statement(query).all()

    json_results = []
    for result in results:
        d = {'id' : result.id,
            'name' : result.name}
        json_results.append(d)

    res = jsonify(items=json_results)
    res.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return res
```

however, when running uWSGI with this file like this :`uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8080 --wsgi-file my_app.py --callable app --processes 4 --threads 2 --stats 127.0.0.1:9191`, and call on it with `SERVER_URL/users/`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "my_app.py", line 18, in users
    results = User.query.from_statement(query).all()
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 428, in __get__
    return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self.registry()
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 903, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 139, in __init__
    bind=db.engine,
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 780, in engine
    return self.get_engine(self.get_app())
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 797, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 473, in get_engine
    self._engine = rv = sqlalchemy.create_engine(info, **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 344, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 73, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 401, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
[pid: 10902|app: 0|req: 3/3] 74.108.216.27 () {40 vars in 708 bytes} [Sun May 18 01:46:00 2014] GET /users/ => generated 0 bytes in 13 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

Comment: is your virtual environment enabled? you might want to enable it from your .bashrc script since running your app will open in a new shell environment, which by default won't have the virtual environment enabled

Comment: Yes my virtual environment is enabled, and I have installed pip and run the uWSGI from the virtual environment

Comment: another thought, perhaps try running "pip freeze | grep psycopg2" and see if the module was actually installed

Comment: `pip freeze | grep psycopg2` returns no results. `sudo pip freeze | grep psycopg2` however returns `psycopg2==2.5.3`

Comment: it's possible that it's a permission issue. try running your app as a super user: sudo uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8080... if this works and you don't want to run your app as a super user (which you probably shouldn't) then uninstall psycopg2 and install it without 'sudo'

Comment: `sudo uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8080` results in `sudo: uwsgi: command not found` which makes sense because wouldn't running the uwsgi with sudo privileges defeat the purpose of the virtual environment?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53891/discussion-between-mike-v-and-gilsho)

Comment: the purpose of a virtual environment is to allow you to have different modules, and perhaps different versions of the same module, installed for different projects that you are working on. For example, if you have project one that requires version 1.0 of a module, and project two that requires version 2.0 of a module, there is no easy way to solve this without using a virtual environment. But regardless, it's not a good idea to run the app as sudo because you can accidentally cause serious damage to your system

Comment: I don't know why "sudo uwsgi" isn't working, perhaps it's a PATH issue, but the problem seems to be that you installed the module using "sudo pip". try running "sudo pip uninstall psycopg2" and then instal it again as "pip install psycopg2"

Comment: That worked! thank you so much! If you summarize this quickly in a an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that you installed psycopg2 as a superuser, i.e. using 'sudo'. When you run commands as a super user, the command gets executed in a different shell that has the superuser's environment, and as a result the package will be installed in a different location in the filesystem that may not be accessible to your 'normal' environment. You need to install the package again as a regular user, i.e. without the leading 'sudo' in order to use the package. In short, just run:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: When I use `pip install psycopg2`, it tries to put it in a directory that it does not otherwise have permission to access!  Install won't work at all without sudo.  I have never had a problem with python packages before and I'm really confused as to why it is so easy to install psycopg2 in a way that makes it invisible to python.

Comment: yeah psycopg is little weird package to install, because it requires that you already have postgresql installed on your machine. Typically, postgresql requires being installed in the restricted parts of the filesystem so it can be accessed as a service, and so needs super user permissions.

Answer (score 7):

I was experiencing problems trying to install this package. Could not install it at all.
https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/

From that page I've found this option:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

and boom! it worked!

Answer (score 3):

Solution: install the package via yum or apt not pip.

```
sudo yum install python-psycopg2
```

and then psycopg2 can be used by all users.

```
pip install psycogp2
```

will fail with permission issue:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.7.6.1.dist-info/METADATA'
```

Comment: pip never works for me had to use yum or apt for apt. on python 2 use sudo apt install python-psycopg2 for python3 use sudo apt install python3-psycopg2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu, and I tried `apt-get` and `pip` to no avail.  I ended up uninstalling from both pip and apt-get, and then downloading the source package from [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/download/).  Once you have the source, you can just run:

```
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

I didn't have to do anything else after that.  Psycopg2 was available as an import within the default installation of python.

It's odd, because the installation instructions specifically recommend using a package if one exists for your OS, but the source method is the only one that worked for me on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this instead:

```
sudo pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I copied the contents of one folder containing a virtual environment to a new one.

Even after running `pip install psycopg2` with the venv active from the cli or from with VS Code,

**My solution** was to delete the virtual environment folder, create a new one and use pip to re-install all of the packages.